# Summing Scenarios from Monte Carlo

Tags: python

I am trying to sum the values in `Callpayoffs`, as they represent the payoffs based on the last price which is generated in the prior path asset price loop. If I run 10 simulations, there should be 10 `Callpayoffs` based on the last price of each simulation path which has 252 price points. Unfortunately I'm not able to add up the values in the `Callpayoffs` list. Would really appreciate any help - the below is a sample of `print(sum(Callpayoffs)`

```
4.620174500863143
22.762337253759725
0
51.97221078945353
```

based on my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import *


def Generate_asset_price(S,v,r,dt):
    return (1 + r * dt + v * sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(0,1))


# initial values
S = 100
v = 0.2
r = 0.05
T = 1
N = 252 # number of steps 
dt = 0.00396825
simulations = 4


for x in range(simulations):
    stream = [100]
    Callpayoffs = []
    t = 0
    for n in range(N):
        s = stream[t] * Generate_asset_price(S,v,r,dt)
        stream.append(s)
        t += 1
    Callpayoffs.append(max(stream[-1] - S,0))   
    print(sum(Callpayoffs))

    plt.plot(stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise `Cardpayoffs` outside `for` loop and call `sum` once you iterated through the list. The following should do the trick:

```
Callpayoffs = []
for x in range(simulations):
    stream = [100]
    t = 0
    for n in range(N):
        s = stream[t] * Generate_asset_price(S,v,r,dt)
        stream.append(s)
        t += 1
    Callpayoffs.append(max(stream[-1] - S,0))   

print(sum(Callpayoffs))
plt.plot(stream)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work, the print(sum(Callpayoffs) is just taking the last value instead of adding all of them up.

Comment: @NovicePythoncharmer The output of the code is the sum of the list which in this case contains 4 elements.

Comment: if you do print(Callpayoffs) at the same indent as the Callpayoffs.append you will see the sum payoffs only gives the last value